# Classifying sequential data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning, sequential-pattern-mining

I am trying to understand what are the best practices to perform supervised machine learning on sequential numerical data. My data looks like following:

```
# sample data for class 'a'
+----+-----+----+------+-----+---+
| id | inv | s1 |  s2  |  s3 | y |
+----+-----+----+------+-----+---+
| 1  | 0.0 | 36 | 0.02 | 0.0 | a |
| 1  | 0.1 | 92 | 0.01 | 8.8 | a |
| 1  | 0.3 |  8 | 0.11 | 8.4 | a |
| 1  | 0.4 |  7 | 0.13 | 8.3 | a |
| 1  | 0.5 | 12 | 0.07 | 8.5 | a |
| 1  | 0.6 | 15 | 0.06 | 8.5 | a |
| 1  | 0.7 | 11 | 0.08 | 8.4 | a |
+----+-----+----+------+-----+---+

# sample data for class 'b'
+----+-----+----+------+-----+---+
| id | inv | s1 |  s2  |  s3 | y |
+----+-----+----+------+-----+---+
| 2  | 0.0 | 16 | 0.10 | 9.0 | b |
| 2  | 0.1 | 12 | 0.20 | 9.0 | b |
| 2  | 0.3 | 24 | 0.11 | 6.4 | b |
| 2  | 0.4 | 28 | 0.16 | 1.3 | b |
| 2  | 0.5 | 10 | 0.12 | 1.5 | b |
| 2  | 0.6 | 11 | 0.11 | 1.5 | b |
| 2  | 0.7 | 12 | 0.01 | 4.4 | b |
+----+-----+----+------+-----+---+
```

So far for my baseline, I have taken some aggregations and did normalization for each id, making structure to look something like:

```
# sample data for class 'a'
+----+---------+---------+---------+---+
| id | avg(s1) | avg(s2) | avg(s3) | y |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---+
| 1  |      50 |    0.05 |     8.2 | a |
| 2  |      20 |    0.15 |     4.0 | b |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---+
```

There are also min, max, variance, avg_lag and other aggregation columns. While it works relatively ok, I am noticing that each class has a set of different patterns that are not being captured using those features.

I am currently in the process of trying to use KNN with DTW as a distance measure, but ideally I would like to avoid using instance-based learning method.

Some other things: 
 - there are three `y` classes 
 - `id` denotes unique number of this sequence 
 - `inv` denotes sequence of events (in this case, it's distance in cm from beginning if that helps) 
 - `s1`, `s2` and `s3` are three different sensors. There are ~6-10 of them, some values are correlated. 
 
 - each `id` has 80-120 rows. 
 - There is relatively large amount of training samples available.

What are some other approaches that I can try?

Comment: Please go through the help page here for info on how to ask questions: http://stats.stackexchange.com/help . From your current question it doesn't seem like you are asking anything specific or have researched your problem but are asking for broad opinion.

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks for comment. I followed link you suggested and went through sections, but I am not sure which guidelines I am violating. I understand that some people can probably write book trying to answer this question, but I am looking for general pointers / expertise of other people who solved something similar. I probably should add that I am relatively new to ML -- I did some research, but was unable to find something that 1) I can understand and 2) Works with numerical data (and not with NLP-like problems).

Comment: Maybe this post will help you edit your post and make it more direct in terms of what you are looking for: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated

Comment: The primary issue I have with the post is "what are best practices" v/s "this is my problem, my current approach, what can I do to improve"

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks a lot for comments -- rules here are a bit different than at SO :) Let me know if I can improve question in any other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach that I have seen used in the past for sequence classification is using Recurrent neural networks.

In your case, the input will be a sequence, and the output will be a class. Please refer this post for more details: [How can recurrent neural networks be used for sequence classification?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129411/how-can-recurrent-neural-networks-be-used-for-sequence-classification)